# terraform aws add route to route table error

Tags: amazon-web-services, routes, terraform

I need to add the same route to a route table (specified by a user as a list) however when I run terraform apply the first time, it errors out with:

> Error applying plan:
>
> 1 error(s) occurred:
>
> - module.vpn.aws_route.route[0]: 1 error(s) occurred:
> - aws_route.route.0: InvalidParameterValue: There is no route defined for '172.64.0.0/16' in the route table. Use CreateRoute instead.
>     status code: 400, request id: b229d66a-e47b-40b2-acf5-6c4c4a8598ba

when I run it the second time (w/o changing anything) it runs fine.

here's the terraform code

```
resource "aws_instance" "vpn" {
  ami = "${var.ami}"
  instance_type = "${var.instance_type}"
  subnet_id = "${var.subnet_id}"
  associate_public_ip_address = "${var.associate_public_ip_address}"
  source_dest_check = "${var.source_dest_check}"
  vpc_security_group_ids = ["${aws_security_group.hub.id}"]
}

resource "aws_route" "route" {
  count = "${length(var.route_tables)}"
  route_table_id = "${element(var.route_tables, count.index)}"
  destination_cidr_block = "${var.destcidrblock}"
  instance_id = "${aws_instance.vpn.id}"
}
```

Comment: What does the plan look like both before you first apply and then before you apply the second time?

Comment: I updated to terraform 0.9.4 from 0.9.3 and I can't replicate this issue. Might have been a bug.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the instance was not ready at the time when you are creating route to it. 
Next time when you tried instance was up and running and it worked.